# ASP.NET C#: How to print a pdf open in the browser using Content-Disposition: inline

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing, response

I am opening a PDF in the browser by specifying the **Content-Disposition** parameter as **inline** to the response object and it is working fine.

My additional requirement is to print this pdf.

I tried using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print()</script>")
```

I added this line of code after `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();` and before `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();` but this isn't printing the page

Comment: You cannot control how the browser opens a PDF. And you cannot send both a file and a response.write to the browser at the same time.

Comment: So it isn't possible at all? Any hacks?